# Python discord bot not respoding to on_message event

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm trying to make a discord bot but the bot is not responding to any of my commands.
He is writing the command when going online but nothing more.
I have given him every permission and intent but it did not help.

```
import discord
import time

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


# Dictionary to store the brake times for each user
brb_times = {}

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Only process messages from other users, not the bot itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("!brb 5"):
        brb_times[message.author.name] = time.time() + 5 * 60
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} has taken a 5-minute brake.")

    elif message.content.startswith("!brb 10"):
        brb_times[message.author.name] = time.time() + 10 * 60
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} has taken a 10-minute brake.")

    elif message.content.startswith("!brb 15"):
        brb_times[message.author.name] = time.time() + 15 * 60
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} has taken a 15-minute brake.")

    elif message.content.startswith("!back"):
        if message.author.name in brb_times:
            brake_time = brb_times[message.author.name]
            del brb_times[message.author.name]
            elapsed_time = time.time() - brake_time
            if elapsed_time > 0:
                await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} is back, but was late by {int(elapsed_time)} seconds.")
            else:
                await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} is back.")
        else:
            await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} was not on a brake.")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")
    await client.get_channel(CENSORED).send("Bot is ready to track breaks!")

client.run("CENSORED")
```

Comment: Does it enter `on_message` at all? What command(s) do you try?

Comment: No,it does not enter the on_message at all. I've tried everything including !brb 5, !brb 10 and !brb 15

Answer (score 0):

You need `message_content` to be `True` in `intents`.

Comment: Every intent is turned to on and the bot has every permission

Comment: In the docs, the description of `discord.Intents.default()` says `A factory method that creates a Intents with everything enabled except presences, members, and message_content.`

Comment: so what should i do to fix the code?

Comment: You can either do `intents.message_content = True` or set `intents` to `discord.Intents.all()`. The latter enables all intents, so you won't need `intents.members = True` if you do choose this method.